# generate select field in django form using model

Tags: django

I'm writing a Django application and building the form manually.

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<input name="name" class="form-control">

<textarea name="description">

<select name="teaching_language">
    <option value="">Value 1</option>
</select>
</form>
```

my `models.py` contains

```
class TeachingLanguage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class META:
        verbose_name_plural = 'teaching_languages'
        db_table = 'languages'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    teaching_language = models.ForeignKey(TeachingLanguage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I have to fill `<option>` by the list of `TeachingLanguage`

The view.py file contains

```
class NewCourse(CreateView):
    model = Course
    fields = ['name', 'teaching_language', 'description']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewCourse, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        teaching_languages = TeachingLanguage.objects.all()
        context['teaching_languages'] = teaching_languages
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**How to render the `teaching_languages` in `select` field to generate a dropdown list?**

Comment: Why are you building the form manually? It would be so much easier to let Django do this for you. It will automatically populate the select field with the available `TeachingLanguage` objects, simply with `{{ form.teaching_languages }}`.

Comment: Because this is the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **must** do it manually rather than just letting Django handle it, then you can simply iterate over the teaching languages that you've passed to the context:

```
<select name="teaching_language">
    {% for lang in teaching_languages %}
    <option value="{{ lang.pk }}">{{ lang }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your template:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<input name="name" class="form-control">

<textarea name="description">

{{ form.teaching_languages }}
</form>
```

This will generate only the teaching_languages field from your form. [Click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for more details.

Also you should remove the `get_context_data` method now because the `form` variable is passed to the template automatically and the form picks-up all the teaching languages automatically as they are set as Foreign Keys in the Course model.

Comment: can I pass `class` and other attributes by using `{{ form.teaching_languages }}`? If yes, how?

Comment: You can use [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) for that. It is very easy to use. And a big advantage of this plugin is that you will add the fields inside your template and not in your back-end code.